# Google BigQuery SQL, I write a SQL maybe not useful, so who can help me?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The sorting default channel name is not display, the landing page is human hair and after viewing human hair, the most viewed products are sorted in descending order.
My English is not good...
I use this SQL, but the hits.ecommerceaction.action_type is maybe 90% is zero

```
SELECT
  hits.product.v2ProductName AS product_Name,
  COUNT( hits.product.v2ProductName )AS product_View,
  hits.page.pagePath as landingPage,
  trafficSource.medium,
  hits.ecommerceaction.action_type as action_type 
FROM (
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitStartTime,
    hits.product.v2ProductName,
    hits.ecommerceaction.action_type,
    totals.transactions,
    hits.page.pagePath ,
    trafficSource.medium
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXX._sessions_],TIMESTAMP("2018-03-01"),TIMESTAMP("2018-06-15") )
    where hits.page.pagePath ='/human-hair.html'
  AND trafficSource.medium!='cpm'
)
GROUP BY
 product_Name,landingPage,trafficSource.medium,action_type
ORDER BY product_View desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sql is working then you don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT
  hits.product.v2ProductName AS product_Name,
  COUNT( hits.product.v2ProductName )AS product_View,
  hits.page.pagePath as landingPage,
  trafficSource.medium,
  hits.ecommerceaction.action_type as action_type 
FROM   TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXX._sessions_],TIMESTAMP("2018-03-01"),TIMESTAMP("2018-06-15") )
where hits.page.pagePath ='/human-hair.html'
AND trafficSource.medium!='cpm'
GROUP BY product_Name,landingPage, trafficSource.medium, action_type
ORDER BY product_View desc
```

Comment: use this sql it's return no records.before i had used this sql ,no recoords.but also thanks brother